# how to pass the viewdata to the target_page of " filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(target_page) "

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, filterattribute

when i write a

> FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter

i can't pass viewdata to the target_page in

`filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(target_page)`

i had tried :

```
filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Add("_errorInfo", "xxxxx");
```

but its not working.